# Let $\varphi : G \rightarrow G/N$. Prove/Dis-prove that there exists a right inverse of $\varphi$ that is *homomorphic*.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism, quotient-group

Statement: Let $G$ be a **finite** group, $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ and let $\varphi: G \rightarrow G/N$ be the cannonical map. Prove/Dis-prove that there exists a right inverse of $\varphi$ that is homomorphic.

Testing the statement with $C_n$ and $D_n$, we see that there is a right inverse which is an homomorphism, for every quotient map.

How does one think about the statement for a general group.

Any hints/ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you mean *right* inverse? Or use composition from left to right? In any case, the answer is **no**, so try to look at more examples. Are you sure you found all quotients of $D_4$?

Comment: @Berci, yes it is the right inverse that I am looking for. One way to find quotients is by finding Normal subgroups. $D_4$ has 3 proper normal subgroups that I am aware of. $N_1=\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ whose quotient is isomorphic to $\{1,r\}$. $N_2=\{1,x^2,r,x^2r\}$ whose quotient is isomorphic to $\{1,x\}$. $N_3=\{1,x^2,xr,x^3r\}$ whose quotient is isomorphic to $\{1,x\}$. Is there anything I am missing, or am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: It's correct. You're missing $N_4=\{1,x^2\}$ and its quotient is in fact not isomorphic to any subgroup of $D_4$.

Comment: @Berci, isn't there a problem with the very good-definition of the only candidate for such a guessed right inverse?

Comment: What do you mean by 'only candidate'?

Comment: @Berci, I mean $\tilde \varphi: G/N\to G$ defined by $Na\mapsto a$.

Comment: That is not a well defined map, as $Na=Nb$ can happen for different $a,b$ (exactly when $ab^{-1}\in N$), unless $N=\{1\}$.

Comment: @Berci, that's precisely what I meant. But how else could a $\tilde\varphi$ act as right inverse of $\varphi$?

Comment: @Berci you are right, (being pedantic) but if we look at the quotient group with $N=N_4$, it is isomorphic to a subgroup of $D_4$ ($N_2$), but a map so created does not give a right inverse as required. And because there is no other subgroup which is isomorphic to the quotient group, we do NOT have a right inverse which is an homomorphism.

Comment: Indeed, you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider $\{1,x^2\}\lhd D_4$ where $x$ is rotation by $+90^\circ$.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose there is, call it $\psi$. Then, by assumption, $\varphi\psi\colon G/N\to G/N$ is the identity map.

Let $K$ be the image of $\psi$ and define $\alpha=\psi\varphi\colon G\to G$. Take $g\in G$; then
$$
\varphi(g\alpha(g^{-1}))=gN\cdot g^{-1}N=N
$$
because $\varphi\alpha=\varphi\psi\varphi=\varphi$.

Therefore $y=g\alpha(g^{-1})\in N$ and we conclude that $g=y\alpha(g)\in NK$. Hence $G=NK$.

Now look for a group $G$ having a proper normal subgroup $N$ so that, for no proper subgroup $K$, we have $NK=G$.

The minimal such example is the cyclic group with four elements.

Answer (score 0):

For $\bar\varphi: G/N\to G$ to be such an inverse (namely $\varphi\bar\varphi=Id_{G/N}$), it must be $\bar\varphi(Na)\in Na, \forall a\in G$. If we further require it to be a homomorphism, then $\bar\varphi(G/N)\le G$. Therefore, the sought map $\bar\varphi$ picks one element out of each coset in a way that the set of such elements is a subgroup of $G$. Take *e.g.* $G:=\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z=\lbrace0,1,2,3\rbrace$ and $N:=\lbrace0,2\rbrace$; thence, $G/N=\lbrace\lbrace0,2\rbrace,\lbrace1,3\rbrace\rbrace$, but neither $\lbrace 0,1\rbrace$ nor $\lbrace 0,3\rbrace$ is a subgroup of $G$: in this case, the canonical map $\varphi$ hasn't got any right inverse which is also a homomorphism.